# Python regular expression: treat apostrophe as text

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to find a word in a text. The caveat is that I need to treat apostrophes as text.

Let me explain with an example. Let's say I'm looking for the word `don` in the text: `don't trust don`. I need to match `don` but not `don't`.

I started with this regex: `r'(?:\b)%s(?:\b)' % re.escape("don")` but here it matches both occurrences of `don`. I then tried `r'(?:\b|\w\')%s(?:\b|\'\w)' % re.escape("don")`, to no avail.

How do I make my regex treat apostrophes as text?

Edit: Some of the edge cases I did not mention: `'don` and `don'` are correct matches whereas `t'don`, `don't` and `'don'` are not.

Comment: This isn't a problem of treating your apostrophes as text. You need to use a lookahead, to prevent matching with apostrophes.

Comment: Is [this](http://regex101.com/r/yV0jK3) what you want to match then?

Comment: @Jerry All the cases you mentioned are correct, PLUS `'don'` should not match (apostrophe before AND after).

Comment: Well, that made the question take quite a different turn, if I say so to myself. I have edited my regex to take into consideration your edge cases.

Comment: @Jerry Yeah, sorry about that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative look-ahead assertion:

```
r'(?:\b)%s(?!\'\w)(?:\b)'
```

I've put this on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wZ1tN5) with a demo.

The negative lookahead makes the expression match `don` *only* if it is not immediately followed by `'\w`. Your version matches anyway, because both of your options in `(?:\b|\'\w)` match.

Comment: This works indeed if the apostrophe is after the word I'm looking for. What if it's before? (think "O'Reilly" and I'm looking for Reilly). This regex doesn't work and I can't understand why: `(?!\w\')(?:\b)don(?!\'\w)(?:\b)`

Comment: Then you need to add a negative look-behind as well: `(?<!\w')%s` makes sure there is no `\w'` in front of whatever you interpolate for `%s`: http://regex101.com/r/tE0qC8

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this to treat all `'` as word characters within your match:

```
r"(?<!')\b%s\b(?!')"
```

It's using a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind to make sure that there're no `'` around the word you want to match.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/qX4qZ8)

---

**EDIT:** After your edge cases, I would suggest this regex instead:

```
r"(?<!\w')(?<!'(?=%s'))\b%s\b(?!'\w)" % re.escape("don")
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bH4vD8)

When matched against:

```
don't
o'don
'don'
don'
'don
```

Only the last two match.

---

**EDIT2:** If you still want to match strings ending or beginning in `'`, then I would advise stepping back to the 'old way' of getting word boundaries too, i.e. trying to match spaces and beginning/end of lines:

```
(?<!\w')(?<!'(?=%s'))(?<=\b|^|\s)%s(?=\b|^|\s)(?!'\w)
```

[Previous sentence demo](http://regex101.com/r/iS5qX4)

[New test case demo](http://regex101.com/r/zJ2hB9)

Comment: You're going to think that I'm pushing my luck (and I am...) but what if the word I'm looking for contains apostrophes? Let's say I'm looking for the string `this is 'don'` in the sentence `No this is not din, this is 'don'`. This regex sadly doesn't work :(

Comment: @PierreMourlanne That's perfectly fine. It's because `'` is not entirely being treated as part of a word (read as `\w`) character. I had the feeling you'd be doing search on those kind of strings, but wasn't entirely sure, so I held that back a bit. But since you bring it up now, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Althgouh this does work as intended on the regex101 demo, Python doesn't accept look-behind variable width-pattern. When I use this regex I get: `sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @PierreMourlanne Oh, silly me again. I'm not sure why it works on there, maybe because of some PCRE adjustments made by the site owner. It's easily fixable, try this: `(?<!\w')(?<!'(?=%s'))(?:(?<=\b)|(?<=\s)|(?<=^))%s(?=\b|^|\s)(?!'\w)`

Comment: Indeed, it fixes this issue. There still is a problem though. If the string I'm looking for is followed by punctuation, the match fails (example: [link](http://regex101.com/r/zT5bZ2)) and I don't understand why since '!' should be matched by the \b

Comment: Well, if I add a '|\W' match after the word ([like here](http://regex101.com/r/wL0fI5) it works but I still don't understand why it wasn't matched by the '\b'.

Comment: @PierreMourlanne I was about to suggest it but was in a meeting with someone. It doesn't match because `'` is not really being treated as a word character even with the workaround. What you might actually do is replace the `\s`s with a `\W` really, so that you can also match `"'don' is coming` as well. `(?<!\w')(?<!'(?=%s'))(?:(?<=\b)|(?<=\W)|(?<=^))%s(?=\b|^|\W)(?!'\w)`